# Проверка значений в списке на NaN

Tags: python, list, numpy, nan

Есть список:

```
u = array([nan,14,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan])
```

Если я проверяю список через `if` на наличие `NaN`, ничего не происходит. `print` не выводит ничего (там может быть хоть слово 'yes' - ничего не выводит):

```
if u[-2] == np.nan:
    print(u[-2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN` (**N**ot **a** **N**umber) - это особый объект, предназначенный для представления всех "не чисел". Одно "не число" вовсе не обязательно должно равняться другому "не числу".

Например если взять одну строку и одну дату - оба являются "не числами", но они не равны друг другу.

Тоже самое происходит с объектом `NaN` - он не равен самому себе:

```
In [131]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[131]: False
```

Поэтому в Numpy существует специальная функция [np.isnan()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) для проверки:

```
In [130]: [x for x in u if not np.isnan(x)]
Out[130]: [14.0]
```

PS если вы не используете модуль Numpy, то в стандартном модуле `math` тоже есть функция [math.isnan()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan).

Comment: @Valent, `if np.isnan(y[-1]): ...` или `if not np.isnan(y[-1]): ...` - в зависимости от того, что вы хотите проверить